# 2D Platformer: DamageEnemy not being called / why is enemy null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´ve been stuck on this code for a few days, I´ve reviewed the video and compared the script to others on this forum but can´t get it to work. I believe I have identified the error but do not understand why the error occurs.

Below is the Weapon.cs script

Basically, DamageEnemy is not being called because enemy remains null.

You´ll notice that I´ve included a few Debug.Log lines in order to see how far it goes. In the console I get the following printouts:

We hit AlienSpaceship and did 1000 damage.

AlienSpaceship

Null

So, if: Enemy enemy = hit.collider.GetComponent();

Why is enemy Null?

My AlienSpaceship has the following components attached: Transform, SpriteRenderer, Seeker (Script), Rigidbody 2D, Enemy AI(script) Circle Collider 2D.

if I change: if(enemy != null) to if(enemy == null), then DamageEnemy is called.

I am running:

Unity Version 2018.3.4f1 Personal

Visual Studio Version 19.9.4

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKgtC_Gy65c&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR42oVBU6K2DIL6Y22Ry9J1c&index=9
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ivFemmpYus&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR42oVBU6K2DIL6Y22Ry9J1c&index=10
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KdS0QzyhCg&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR42oVBU6K2DIL6Y22Ry9J1c&index=11

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fireRate = 0;
    public int Damage = 10;
    public LayerMask whatToHit;

    public Transform BulletTrailPrefab;
    public Transform MuzzleFlashPrefab;
    float timeToSpawnEffect = 0;
    public float effectSpawnRate = 10;

    public float lifeTime; 
    float timeToFire = 0;
    Transform firePoint;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        firePoint = transform.Find("FirePoint");
        if (firePoint == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No firePoint? WHAT?!");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (fireRate == 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                Shoot();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > timeToFire)
            {
                timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
                Shoot();
            }
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
        Vector2 firePointPosition = new Vector2(firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firePointPosition, mousePosition - firePointPosition, 100, whatToHit);

        if (Time.time >= timeToSpawnEffect)
        {
            Effect();
            timeToSpawnEffect = Time.time + 1 / effectSpawnRate;
        }

        Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, (mousePosition - firePointPosition) * 100, Color.cyan);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, hit.point, Color.red);
            Debug.Log("We hit " + hit.collider.name + " and did " + Damage + " damage.");

            Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);  // This is a test to detect the collision.

            Enemy enemy = hit.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>();

            Debug.Log(enemy); // This is a test to detect that the enemy was created.

            if (enemy != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Inside the loop"); // This is  test to detect if inside the loop...
                enemy.DamageEnemy(Damage);
                Debug.Log("We hit " + hit.collider.name + " and did " + Damage + " damage.");
            }
        }
    }

    void Effect()
    {
        Instantiate(BulletTrailPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        Transform clone = Instantiate(MuzzleFlashPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation) as Transform;  // why cast?
        clone.parent = firePoint;
        float size = Random.Range(0.6f,0.9f);
        clone.localScale = new Vector3(size, size, 0f);
        Destroy(clone.gameObject, lifeTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the "Enemy" script actually exist on the collider that you're hitting? If it's, say, on a parent or child GameObject then you will get a Null.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I figured it out this morning when I woke up. I though there was a problem with the code itself but it turns out through I had the script in my Assests file, I had neglected to add it as a component to the AlienSpaceship Gameobject.

Answer (score 0):

## `GetComponent()` returns null if no component is found on the `GameObject`

See [the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) for details on what GetComponent returns.